# what is the equivalent of "startup.cs"(.Net Core) in my .Net framework application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

`Startup.cs` has some methods which can be used to configure swagger to add file upload functionalities , now in which file in .NET Framework can i do the same functionalities?

Comment: May be you are looking for `Global.asax`?

Comment: yeah i guess global.asax can do the work , i will let you know if it works. thanks!

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov 100% `global.asax.cs` some full framework MVC or API projects also contain startup.cs, but if op asking this question it's global.asax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said you want to `configure Swagger` in `dot net framework` so you need to `install Swashbuckle`  just open `package manager` and type following `commands`

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle -Version 5.6.0
```

then look in your `App_Start` file you will find `SwaggerConfig.cs` where you can configure it

[image]

the minimum, you’ll need this line to `enable Swagger and Swagger UI`.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
  .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API"))
  .EnableSwaggerUi();
```

> [Look here for long Explanation](http://wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/)

Comment: Hello @ArunPratap actually what i want to do is that i want to add a file upload button in my swagger but i am not able to do so because even if i enable swagger UI i don't think i will have a button to upload files !